# MonoTouch:OwnerDrawnElement: Change Draw() on Selected to make it flash?

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

**MonoTouch.Dialog:**

Using a custom **OwnerDrawnElement**, I create the **Element** with a custom **Draw()**

The Draw() is fired when the element is selected.

How can I tell if the Draw() is fired due to a user **Selecting** it so that I can change the UI to indicate a **Select**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside this method in the custom **OwnerDrawnElement**, check for the Highlighted state:

```
public override void Draw (RectangleF bounds, CGContext context, UIView view)
{
    bool highlighted = this.GetActiveCell().Highlighted;
    if(highlighted) ....
}
```